# Kafka & Spring Batch - How to read ONLY uncommitted messages from the same topic?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-batch, spring-kafka

I am working on a small batch with Spring batch and Kafka that reads json data from a Kafka topic, converts it to a Student object, changes a value and sends it back into a Kafka topic.
Everything is working fine, but my only problem is that my consumer is ALWAYS reading from the begging of the topic.
I need it to read from the last non consumed message.
I have already added those properties :

```
ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG to earliest
ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG to false
ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG to a random value
```

But this doesn't seem to work, on start-up of the consumer, it processes all the messages. Anybody has an idea on how to do it with Spring Batch and Kafka please ? This is my code :

**BatchStudent.java** :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BatchStudent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BatchStudent.class, args);
    }

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    private final KafkaTemplate<Integer, Student> template;
    private final KafkaProperties properties;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.consumer}")
    private String topic;

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Student, Student> customItemProcessor() {
        return new CustomProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    Job job() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(start())
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaItemWriter<Integer, Student> writer() {
        return new KafkaItemWriterBuilder<Integer, Student>()
                .kafkaTemplate(template)
                .itemKeyMapper(Student::getId)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaItemReader<Integer, Student> reader() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.putAll(this.properties.buildConsumerProperties());

        return new KafkaItemReaderBuilder<Integer, Student>()
                .partitions(0)
                .consumerProperties(props)
                .name("students-consumer-reader")
                .saveState(true)
                .topic(topic)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Step start() {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step")
                .<Student, Student>chunk(10)
                .writer(writer())
                .processor(customItemProcessor())
                .reader(reader())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**app.yml**

```
spring.batch.initialize-schema: always

#Conf Kafka Consumer
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
#spring.kafka.consumer.group-id: student-group
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages: '*'
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type: com.org.model.Student

#Conf Kafka Producer
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092

#Conf topics
spring.kafka.template.default-topic: producer.student
kafka.topic.consumer: consumer.student
```

**Student.java**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    Integer id;
    Integer count;
}
```

**CustomProcessor.java**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Student, Student> {

    @Override
    public Student process(Student studentRecieved) {
        final Student studentSent = new Student();
        studentSent.setId(studentRecieved.getId());
        studentSent.setCount(200);
        return studentSent;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: what happen when you set  auto-offset-reset: latest ?

Comment: Same behaviour, and I think that its default value is latest

Comment: If you set groupId to a random value (presumably every time you start the consumer) then how is it supposed to pick up the offsets from a previous run? They will be saved under a completely different groupId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Everything is working fine, but my only problem is that my consumer is ALWAYS reading from the begging of the topic. I need it to read from the last non consumed message.

Spring Batch 4.3 introduced a way to consume records from the offset stored in Kafka. I talked about this feature in my talk at Spring One last year: [What's new in Spring Batch 4.3?](https://youtu.be/AfR8jjELBOU?t=435). You can configure the kafka reader with a custom starting offset in each partition by using [setPartitionOffsets](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReader.html#setPartitionOffsets-java.util.Map-):

```
Setter for partition offsets. This mapping tells the reader the offset to start reading
from in each partition. This is optional, defaults to starting from offset 0 in each
partition. Passing an empty map makes the reader start from the offset stored in Kafka
for the consumer group ID.
```

You can find a complete example in [this test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReaderTests.java#L258).

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud Ben Hassine. I think there is one more problem to it. The ParitionsOffset is always initialized with the last offset we read.  After rerunning the JOB.. The Reader start reading from the same offset , not zero. I know I can set them by using setting, but I dont have that information in current context of new JOB. I only need to call kafkaConsumer and get the offset and then increment it by 1.

Comment: The offset is stored in the execution context of spring batch and in kafka. It is up to you choose where to read it from on a restart of a failed job instance. By default, a restart will make the job read data from the last offset stored in the execution context of spring batch. If you want to restart from the offset stored in Kafka, you can pass an empty partitionOffset map.

Comment: I got your point and for the restart, i am able to do that also. The problem is with new JOb Instance. Basically it doesnt pass this check in Open method in KafkaItemReader, if (this.saveState && executionContext.containsKey(TOPIC_PARTITION_OFFSETS)) . It starts reading from the last offset in map Partitions offset. The only option I have to get that offset is via KafkaOffset or I should set in some global context.

Comment: Also it will not start from the last offset stored in the execution context automatically. I followed your test cases, we should need to set the PartitionOffset with Topic Partions after get from the execution context. Basically, KafkaItemReader needs to be re-initialize.